# How to convert Timestamp Datatype value in SQL in Datetime format in C# by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I am using LINQ and in my database Tstamp fileld with Timestamp datatype. Now i want to fetch data from SQL by using LINQ query and it returns me Tstamp datafield value in System.Data.Linq.Binary datatype. Now i want to convert this Binary datatype value in Datetime format but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` != `timestamp`

A SQL `timestamp` is a monotonically increasing number, expressed as binary. Not time. Nothing to do with time, except that they both roll ever-forwards. Which is why `timestamp` (as a keyword) is now deprecated (as confusing), and replaced with [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).

You cannot get time from a `timestamp`. If you want the time, store the time as `datetime`.

Comment: then what is the use of timestamp datatype in SQL and why we use this?

Comment: `timestamp` (and `rowversion`, which are synonymous) are used to perform optimistic concurrency and change detection, since you can easily check via a single field if anything has changed. That is because ***any*** change to that record automatically changes the `timestamp`/`rowversion` to a new (higher) number.

Comment: Then can i convert the date to timestamp using to-timestamp('gps_timestamp','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), in sql

Comment: @user285oo6 by "timestamp", do you mean a `datetime`? or do you mean a `rowversion`? Both are referred to as "timestamp"s, but they are very different things. What do *you* mean by "timestamp" ?

Comment: datetime the one which is accurate to the nano seconds

Comment: @user285oo6 `datetime` is accurate to about 0.003 seconds, so: a few milliseconds; to emphasize, the `timestamp` referred to *in this question* **has nothing whatsoever to do with time**, so isn't accurate to any time precision. `datetime2` is accurate to about 100 nanoseconds. As for formatting: *why* would you do that in SQL? that makes no sense. Formatting data is not a job for SQL... you should do that in the app tier (whether that is server-based on client-based)

Comment: @Marc the column name gps_timestamp is of date data type and i want to convert it into time stamp(date time) so as to perform the between and i am unable to it because i got an gps_timestamp as invalid identifier

Comment: @user285oo6 I'm not quite sure why you're asking me in the comments here; none of that has *anything* to do with this question/answer. Frankly you should ask a separate question - just: *don't use the term timestamp* - it is unhelpful and ambiguous. Conversion from `date` to `datetime` / `datetime2` is implicit / automatic - and works fine, so you would need to be (in your actual question) a lot more specific about your scenario, what exactly you are doing when this error happens, and what exactly the error says.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL timestamp is not actually a datetime data type.  It is an auto-generated binary data type used for versioning your row.  Therefore, it cannot be converted to a datetime value in C#.

See [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: If we want to show timestamp value on aspx page then how we can show this value???

Comment: @Gaurav Agrawal - the timestamp data type does not usually contain data valuable for display, as it is usually just auto generated binary (somewhat random) data. If you need to store a date data type, use the datetime datatype in SQL. However, if you must display this data, you will need to convert the data to a string using something like Convert.ToBase64String()